# How to make width of html grow when web is downscaled?

Tags: html, web, tailwind-css

How to scale a width of background with scale of app? i want it to be 100% on small screens, but scale with the size of window, but without breakpoints
[Image to describe what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0IVd.png) i need to scale width of child div when screen gets smaller
Here's my code

```
<div className="bg-gray-200 w-[100%]">
  <div className="w-[50%] mx-auto h-[100vh] bg-white">
    <h1>Movies</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: By removing `w-[50%]`? Replace with `w-full`?

Comment: I deleted parent div and set margin: auto & min-width on remain div, thats what i need